Relation between the field and $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra generated by eigenvalues of modular form
Cross-posted from MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4944262/relation-between-the-field-and-mathbbz-algebra-generated-by-eigenvalues-of
Let $f$ be a cusp form of weight $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ for the group $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$. Assume that it is a normalized Hecke eigenform, with eigenvalues (which equal the Fourier coefficients) $a_f(n)$. Let $F$ be the field generated by $\{a_f(p): p \text{ is prime}\}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, and let $Z$ be the $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra generated by $\{a_f(p): p \text{ is prime}\}$. Then, it is a fact that $F$ is a finite filed extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.
Question 1: what is the relation between $F$ and $Z$?
I know that (fact), there exists a number field whose ring of integers contains all the Fourier coefficients $a_f(n)$, ($n\in \mathbb{N}$). Let $\mathcal{O}_F$ denote the ring of integers of $F$.
Question 2: Is there any relation between $\mathcal{O}_F$ and $Z$?
Question 3: In the above case, will equality hold? (i.e., $\mathcal{O}_F=Z$?)
I could find any questions on the site which answers this. Any reference for the same will be helpful.

Necessarily $\mathcal O_F \supset Z$.  They need not be equal.  See examples on the LMFDB (I think $[\mathcal O_F : Z]$ is called something like coefficient ring index there.)

And this index must be finite.
